# Cannot re-add omnibox opensearch for our website

Tags: omnibox

We don't manage to solve the following issue for a while now:

Our website has an opensearch and it works fine, when the user opens our website, the opensearch will be added to his custom searches.

But on my specific Google user it is not being added. I used to have it and then I deleted it (it was as a default search engine if that matters). Since then it doesn't add it to my Chrome when I reopen our website. It does work if I create another user on my Chrome, but the moment I will sign in with my Google user it removes it from the custom search engines!

Tried lots of stuff:

1. Cleaned all the possible cache
2. Tried on another PC with my user. On another PC it works, as long as I don't sign it with my Google user.
3. Tried to add it manually, then it simply doesn't search.
4. Deleting History Provider Cache file
5. Disabling ALL my extensions

How to clean up this omnibox cache or something? Where is it stored?

It seems like this omnibox history is somehow stored in my Google account. Does Google account remembers the custom searches that I delete and then doesn't add them automatically?

Thanks in advance!